# Change Text in id/class based on the page they redirected from in php

Tags: php

i wan to change the text in a DIV based on the page they redirected from..

is there any if condition for this... or any code which helps me to do this... searched all the internet.. but didn't find it :(

if users reducers from google.com i want to show hello googler! if he came from my friends site, hello xxx reader. (`Xxx = my friends blog name`). if he is a direct visitor, hello visitor. like this....

hope you guys can help me! Thanks!!

**UPDATE**

in other question in stackoverflow, i found this ode (ASP.NET) i need a similar one in php.

in this ASP code he writes `ENDS WITH(" ")` but i want to write the FULL url there.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  string requestUrl = "";

  . . .

  if (requestUrl.ToString().EndsWith("Page1.aspx"))
    label.Text = "foo";
  else
    label.Text = "bar";
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Referer is not reliable.

Comment: @Mr.Alien sorry i really didn't get you... can you please expand this.. please

Answer (score 1):

`$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` will do exactly what you need.

```
if (strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], 'facebook.com') !== false) {
    // Facebook brought me to this page.
}

else if (strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], 'google.com') !== false ) {
    // Google brought me to this page.
}
```

**EDIT**

```
else if (strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], 'xxx.blogspot.com') !== false ) {
    // Your friend brought me to this page.
}
```

Comment: just make sure you have an option for blank, as my HTTP_REFERER is striped by the firewall

Comment: @user2373405 first google about `identity operator` and you will know what does `!==` mean.. @Dagib Yes! REFERER is not always set because clients can disable their browser to send it in the request.

Comment: @Veekay thank you bro. but got error in the line where 1st `}` ends (3rd line in your code). code i have used
`<?php
if (strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], 'facebook.com') !== false) {
  echo"Facebook brought me to this page"
}

if (strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], 'google.com') !== false ) {
    echo"Google brought me to this page"
}


?>` Please Check Ones Bro.